Screen zoomed in Virtual Box
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 (MATE) on the lastest version of VirtualBox (my pc is Windows11 Pro).
The problem is that everything in Ubuntu is big and zoomed in, so that I cannot see entire windows content (see attached picture)!

I have installed the Guest Additions
I changed the scale factor in Settings
I switched between full and not-full screen mode
I changed resolution settings
I tried in Ubuntu settings (aspect)

Nothing worked. What should I do ?


Have you tried changing the Graphics Controller in the VirtualBox settings for the VM? See here.

Yes, I did. Some of them does not work. Only the default one works (no gray screen etc..)
